# In C++, how can I test for one of several flags combined with "|" in one argument?

Tags: c++, function, arguments

I have next code:

```
int main()
{
 OwnSelect(23, FD_READ | FD_WRITE); // <---- Several arguments as one
 return 0;
}

int OwnSelect(SOCKET s, long lNetworkEvents)
{
 // How can i check that FD_READ has been passed?
 if(lNetworkEvents == FD_READ)
 {
  // never here
 }
 return 0;
}
```

How can i check that FD_READ has been passed no matter if another FD has been passed with FD_READ.
Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure there's a duplicate or two, but `lNetworkEvents & FD_READ`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you're missing out on a bit of basic bit manipulation here. You're OR'ing FD_READ and FD_WRITE (| = bitwise OR), thereby setting the bits indicated by both values, as a parameter. To check if FD_READ was passed, you need to AND lNetworkEvents with FD_READ and check if the result equals FD_READ, like so:

`if (FD_READ == (lNetworkEvents & FD_READ)) { ... }`

This of course assuming that FD_READ and FD_WRITE are values that were meant to be used this way (i.e. typically don't have overlapping bits).

edit: fixed, wabepper is absolutely right :) oops!

Comment: Even if `FD_READ` does define a boolean (which is likely, given its name), this sort of writing, depending on implicit type conversions to `bool`, is obfuscating.

Answer (score 2):

By using `&`:

```
if ((lNetworkEvents & FD_READ) == FD_READ) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( (iNetworkEvents & FD_READ) != 0 )
```

is what you're looking for here.  This works well as long as the
"argument" in question is a single bit (a boolean).  For more complex
operations, like those on the `floatfield` in `fmtflags`, you'll need
to compare with the correct value:

```
switch (myFlags & std::ios_base::floatfiled )
{
case std::ios:base::fixed:
    //  ...

//  ...
}
```

Finally if the field is an integral value (e.g. `0...7` on 3 bits),
you'll have to both mask and shift to get the correct value.  (If the
value is signed, it's even more complex.)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/ - that might help you

a very simplistic explanation: imagine

```
FD_READ = 0b01
FD_WRITE = 0b10
```

then passing `FD_READ | FD_WRITE` will give you `0b11` as argument

to check if `FD_READ` is there basically is to check if that last bit is `1`, doable by:

```
x & 0b01 // aka
x & FD_READ
```