# Program File (x86) when checked for dwfileattributes Returns a value 73745. I need help to know what combination adds up to this value?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, recursion, directory

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
.
.
.
.
if(FindFileData.dwFileAttributes == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{
.
}
```

This failed for program files and I found it online that it is combination of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY` and not `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`. Similarly I need help for program files (x86)?

Comment: Nothing to do with the code here. I need to know how to access program files (x86) using WIN32_FIND_DATA object. When I compared FindFileData.dwFileAttributes with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY its false.
Actually I am new to this website and still searching how to format the code. I have given proper lines and spaces when typing, but result came like this.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to create an application similar to windows explorer using MFC. So while recursing through the directory tree, when it reaches progam files  (x86) it gets skipped and goes to next.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155010/findfirstfile-findnextfile-recursive-search-not-finding-program-files

See the last comment in this post. That shows how to check for program files. I need to know the similar kind of combination to be used for checking program files (x86).

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C++, how can I test for one of several flags combined with "|" in one argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11259846/in-c-how-can-i-test-for-one-of-several-flags-combined-with-in-one-argumen)

Comment: This is a really bad question. You need to start to actually **read** what people are saying in reply.

Comment: @kiDDevil: Waste of time, altough your question is too bad, I want see how your "Explorer" enumerate system folders using WIN32_FIND_DATA.

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
if((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
{

}
```

That way you check if FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY is one of the flags, instead of if it is the only flag.

Comment: With this method I can check whether the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY bits are set or not. But I need the to go inside program files (x86) while doing recursion. So I need to know what all are the return value for FindFileData.dwFileAttributes.

Comment: Your question was why was your if-statement failing for "Program files". My answer is to the point. Read your question - you put an if, and then say "This failed for program files". By failed you mean the if wasn't passed. So my answer explained to you why it did not pass, and how to fix it so it passes.

Comment: It passes for all the folder in C drive except program files and program files (x86). For program files I got the solution from 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155010/findfirstfile-findnextfile-recursive-search-not-finding-program-files

and I am searching for program files (x86) now. I will do one thing, Using the methode that you have given I will try to use AND operation for all the 17 return chances and check what all are relevant for Program Files (x86)

Comment: Wait, so you didn't even try my method before declaring it doesn't help you? Don't you see a problem there? "Your solution didn't work for me. Why? Cause I didn't try it." First you can't format your code, and now that.

Comment: Your answer does an AND operation to bits of FindFileData.dwFileAttributes and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY and if it contains FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY that will be true. 
I completely understood that brother. I need to know what all are present as a return for FindFileData.dwFileAttributes when it is Program Files (x86).

Comment: Why? What for do you need to know the rest of the flags, now that your `if` is working? For curiosity, or are you going to use it in your code?

Comment: I am populating a tree from directories present in C drive in a MFC.
So need to use recursion. If it's a directory the function should call itself. For both these program files and program files (x86) that condition fails and function is not calling itself.
for program files its a combination of FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY + FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY. Similarly I need the combination for program files (x86)

Comment: Did you try running my code? Did you try changing your if-statement in your program and seeing if it actually works? I bet you still haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

[WIN32_FIND_DATA structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365740%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
dwFileAttributes
The file attributes of a file.

For possible values and their descriptions, see File Attribute Constants.
```

[File Attribute Constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The `dwFileAttributes` field is a **bitmaks**, it can hold multiple attributes at a time, one bit per attribute (up to 32 attributes max). A value of `73745` (hex `0x12011`) contains the following attributes:

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY
1 (0x1)
```

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY
16 (0x10)
```

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED
8192 (0x2000)
```

```
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_VIRTUAL
65536 (0x10000)
```

You MUST use the `&` (AND) operator to test for the presence of individual bits, eg:

```
if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) == FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
```

Or simply:

```
if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I want is what all to be checked for Program Files (x86). I don't have any problem with if loop now. Only thing is it fails for Program Files (x86).
For all other directories If loop works with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY.

Comment: Am I the only one who can't make heads or tails from that sentence? I mean he contradicts himself, he says that the if-statement works, but then goes on to say it doesn't work for Program Files. @kiDDevil, excuse me for asking, but is English your native language? Because if not, that would at least explain why what you say makes no sense.

Comment: NO English is not my native language.
I am working on recursive directory search dear @sashoalm . So the loop is working for all directories in C Drive except program files and program files (x86). And I found a fix for program files and still searching for a fix for program files (x86).

Comment: @kiDDevil: What EXACTLY is failing for you? You need to be more specific. Please update your question to show your actual code, and explain where and how it is failing. Your code is looking for `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`, and `Program Files (x86)` reports `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`, so what is the problem? And what "fix" did you have to use to handle `Program Files`? You should not have had to use any "fix" to handle `Program Files` special.

Comment: Please go through the comments @RemyLebeau

Comment: @kiDDevil: I have, but you have not answered everything that was asked of you. If you are still having the problem, then you are still not handling the attributes/recursion correctly, but noone can tell you why because you still have not shown your actual code that is failing.